# how did this work? export to excel

Tags: php, excel

how does this code work? 1st page:

```js
function excel(){
  l=window.open('export_excel.php', '_blank');
  l.focus();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="excel()">Clicky</button>
```

2nd page ('export_excel.php'):

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>col1</th>
  <th>col2</th>
  <th>col3</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>data1-1</td>
  <td>data1-2</td>
  <td>data1-3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>data2-1</td>
  <td>data2-2</td>
  <td>data2-3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>data3-1</td>
  <td>data3-2</td>
  <td>data3-3</td>
 </tr>
</table>



<?php

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="excel.xls";<script>window.close();</script>');
//header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

?>
```

it exports the entire table to an excel file(excel.xls) i mean this works like a charm to me, (i needed a code that when i press a button it will make a table(at a new page) then export it in an excel file(then download the file automatically then close the page)) i've tried ALOT like ALOT, but nothing work, 
i discovered this when i was erasing some code i forgot to erase these particular lines, i just dont understand why and how does these lines work... can anyone help?

Comment: That's html. Calling it excel does not magically make it an excel file

Comment: It works because MS Excel is capable of importing html markup (albeit rather limited), but doesn't really create a native-format Excel file